# how to implement AsyncTask in titanium studio

Tags: java, android-asynctask, titanium

I'm working on a mobile app project in Titanium Studio (version 3.1.1). It was designed few years ago and now the app crashes on new android os (Android 4.0 and above). It crashes because the new android os does not allow network calls on main UI tread. I know the solution to this is to use AsyncTask and perform network calls on background thread. All the tutorials I found online uses JAVA libraries and eclipse. I have no idea how to implement AsyncTask in titanium studio. Please help me to figure out how to do Async task in Titanium.

Comment: I was searching for the same recently and came across this - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15787?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel